# Is it possible to modify the onload event after the first time a form is opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, onload

I have an empty onload event that I don't want to call the very first time the form is loaded. Is it possible to load the form, and then when the form closes, it injects another method into the onload event for when the form needs to be opened again?

This is how I want it to be the first time I open a form:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

This is how I want it to be the next time I open the form:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LoadData();
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Simply use `if` condition inside to call either one or another method.

Comment: Give the form a static bool classvariable that you can check in the Load Event and change its value after first call.

Comment: how might I write this?

Comment: Use an application settings entry of type `bool` to detect the first run and set it's default value to `true`. So you can handle the `Load` event as so: `if (Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun) { Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun = false; } else { LoadData(); }`

Comment: I tried to use this, but it cant find 'Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun'

Comment: Oh, you were meaning I have to create an entry in the settings